# Typescript type guard losing type definition when imported

Tags: typescript

ok I have bit of a weird situation, I have a custom typescript type guard in one file:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import { JSONSchemaWrapper } from 'types/JSONSchema'

export const isJsonSchema = (jsonSchema: any): jsonSchema is JSONSchemaWrapper => {
  const _jsonSchema = jsonSchema as JSONSchemaWrapper
  return _.isPlainObject(_jsonSchema.properties)
}
```

And when I import it, it is pulled through at `: jsonSchema is any` rendering the type check kinda pointless.

What is weird is if I copy and paste the code into the file I am using it in, everything works. It seems to be something about the import that is losing the `is JSONSchemaWrapper` and becoming `is any`
see screenshots:

When typeguard in another file:
[image]

When typeguard code is pasted directly into this file:

[image]

Also I'm on "typescript": "^3.9.5"

Comment: What is `'types/JSONSchema'`? Is that an npm dependency or a file in your codebase? If it's a local file, does the problem still happen if you use a relative path like `./types/JSONSchema`?

Comment: Great, spot @alex-wayne, changing it to `../types/JSONSchema` totally fixed it. Hmm, should I take this down now as it wasn't an actual problem?